# c++ equivalent of JMX?

Tags: c++, jmx

Can any one suggest c++ equivalent of JMX ?

Answer (score 2):

CMX is a little C and C++ library which allows to expose metrics like in JMX. It doesn't support operations, but already the fact that you get to know whats happening in your process quite cool. And its very lightweight in terms of SLOC and dependencies (none). Is uses shared memory to allows low latency, non-blocking operations and thus is even real-time compliant.

http://cern.ch/cmx

Felix

Answer (score 1):

C++ is pretty much OS agnostic, in the case of JMX when using C++ you would have to reach outside of C++ and dip your hand into the OS API.